# How to enable windows phone lock screen while debugging?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, lockscreen

I am trying to figure out my bug, which occurs when lock screen is called automatically, but while debugging the auto lock screen is disabled.

Does Visual Studio have an option to enable auto lock screen or something?

Comment: Have you got chance to try below answer? Is it working for you?

Comment: @Jack Yes, I was, but it's not helping. The problem is only when lock screen is called automatically, not by my self.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried below steps and it works for me.

To simulate locking or unlocking the phone

1. Run your app on the emulator or a connected device, with or without
   debugging.
2. In Visual Studio, on the Tools menu, open Simulation Dashboard. Find
   the Lock Screen section of the dashboard.
3. To engage the lock screen and lock the phone, select Locked.
4. Test how your app handles deactivation.
5. To disengage the lock screen and unlock the phone, select Unlocked.
6. Test how your app handles activation.

I have referred below URL
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206951(v=vs.105).aspx